# Codenameone FontImage with a placeholder

Tags: netbeans, codenameone

I want to generate a Font Image icon with a placeholder and set it to  a label. Is it possible?.

Comment: Hi ! 
I don't understand what do you mean by "add a placeholder" to an image ?

Comment: Basically I want to generate a icon with either a circle or a rounded square  as the placeholder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand what you want, i think you have to use FontImage to generate your Image and apply a mask to make it round.
 
You can't set a image as a placeholder for a Label but you can add an Image next to a Label (up, bottom, left or right)

```
Image img = FontImage.createFixed(...);
Label lbl = new Label("Some Text Here...",img);
lbl.setTextPosition(Component.[TOP/BOTTOM/LEFT/RIGHT]);
```

Hope i answer your question

Comment: I've got it now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a placeholder for URLImage or something else?

Assuming that's what you mean you can use the API [toEncodedImage](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/FontImage.html#toEncodedImage--) to convert the `FontImage` to an image that can be used as a placeholder.

Comment: Not a URLImage, its a FontImage Icon. I think I will have to define it as a theme.